# Generate 1000V 30A AC from a 12V lead acid battery for a short period, but in a cycle

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, high-voltage, high-current

I am trying to trigger a device which requires a current of 1000V 30A current for operation, but for a very short period. It just needs to be powered for a maximum of 50-100 milliseconds but 6-8 times every seconds. Is it possible to implement from a 100Ah lead acid battery?

In that case how quickly will the battery be fully drained?

I have a circuit using some sort of extreme high tension, but I am wondering if it only provides high voltage and little concerned about the current.

[image]

Based on the comments, I feel its less achievable so straight. But if I am OK with 230V will it be possible in certain extend??

Comment: a rough guess that you would require a lead acid battery that contains between 100 and 150 cells .... your description indicates that the device would be using 30 kW, with a duty cycle of between 30% and 80%

Comment: Just to follow up to what jsotola is saying, a duty cycle of 30 percent with 30 kW power is an average power of 9 kW. I am not sure a 12 V 100 Ah battery is capable of delivering 9 kW but if it is, it will not be able to do it for more than a minute or two. If the duty cycle is 80 percent, then the situation is even worse (24 kW average). This is just based on the information you have presented.

Comment: 30 kW @12V means a pulse of 2500A from the battery system. Most large auto batteries can supply about 600-800A peak, so you'd need at least 3 to have any chance of success in a forward conversion. In addition  the magnetics would be impressive to get it to 1000V (peak, I assume). You'd be better charging a capacitor bank to 1000v and discharging that into your load. You can get high voltage FETs that could do this.

Comment: 6-8 times a second means every 125-170 ms. 50-100 ms out of every 125-170 is *not* a small amount. If you needed this for, say, 10ms out of every 10s, then you could use something like the charge pumps used for camera flashes, but you're asking for a ridiculous amount of power.

Comment: If I am compromising the voltage part to 230V 30A (7Kw) will it be achievable in some extend??

Comment: At 7kW levels, you're talking almost what an electric car takes. And those dont use lead acid batteries because it would be too many amps for the space available. A typical auto lead acid battery is say, 200AH, with probably max safe continuous current of about 50A ? So, you can hope to get 500W sustained. Maybe 1000W at your dutycycle. And a 230V, 30A transformer ? Wow, that will be huge. At the 12V side, you're talking 100A, and hence, some really thick wire!! Are you trying to make an arc welder from a car battery ?

Comment: Guessing your skill level based on the wording of the question, I think you've bitten off more than you can chew, and that it will not be possible.

Comment: @Drew Agree with you bro.. Just a beginner doing totally based on these schematics from internet... Actually from software field... :)

Comment: Excuse me… 30A ?! are you sure you are expected to survive the experiment? even 30mA at 1000V would be quite dangerous

Comment: Tell us more about the device you are triggering.

Comment: If trying to design this seriously, you'd be looking  at about about 8 to 10 TO-247 SiC MOSFETs and quite a few wound components to achieve the peak powers you need. How big is your battery is the next question. Hint: it needs to be big.

Comment: What can you compromise on? Can it be mains powered? Why can you accept a lower voltage? What is this load that you think initially needs 1000 V, then 230 V will do?

Comment: Your time on/off requirement is unclear. Please edit it to make it clear. || Knowing what you want to actually achieve will greatly help people to give a good answer. || This is a very significant task. The circuit shown shows the principle involved but not how much work us involved in doing it in practice.

Answer (score 5):

You require a circuit to provide \$ 1000V \times 30A = 30kW \$ of power, for a period of 50ms, every \$ \frac{1}{6Hz} = 170ms\$.

On average this is \$ \frac{50ms}{170ms} \times 30kW = 8.8kW\$

If your circuit was 100% efficient, this represents \$ I = \frac{P}{V} = \frac{8.8kW}{12V} = 730A \$ of average battery current, peaking at \$ \frac{30kW}{12V} = 2500A \$. Right off the bat, this is infeasible without using 2 or 3 batteries in parallel, and absolutely monstrous cables.

That little circuit you provide can't even get 1% of that. This is a job for multiple transistors on heat sinks the size of your fist, and cooling to match.

If you could use a single fully-charged 100Ah battery, it would be exhausted in \$ \frac{100Ah}{730A} = 0.14h\$, or 8 minutes. Probably much sooner, considering things like battery internal resistance and circuit inefficiency. The battery would also get dangerously hot.

You can mitigate cable and battery size requirements by reducing current demand, which you achieve by placing batteries in series, for say 4 × 12V = 48V. Then the batteries would only need to supply a quarter of the current for the same power output.

The transformer you require would also be a monster. That one in your microwave oven? Not even close. Somewhere between that and the one on the pole in your street.

Reducing the required output voltage to 230V will help, but only by a factor of 4. You may have left the realm of ludicrous power, but it's still a very difficult goal to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.. Honestly I am very beginner with electronics and ofcourse this power electronics.. A friend of mine suggested something to try and this question as part of that.. Anyway canceling it on the road.. :)

Answer (score 1):

A single lead acid battery is unable to do this. What do you need 30kW for? Are you driving a motor?

Let's do the math.

- 1000V X 30A = 30000W
- 30000W X 30% duty cycle = 9000W
- 9000W / 12V = 750A

So your battery will need to be able to source 750 amps to get that power, at 30% duty cycle.

100Ah / 750A = 0.133 hours, or just about 8 minutes.

A motor requires much more than its running power at startup. Let's assume you need to run all 30000W for one second.

- 30000W / 12V = 2500A.
- 100Ah / 2500A = 0.04 hours, or 2 and a half minutes.

So, you could CONCEIVABLY do it, but most lead acid batteries are unable to source over 600-900 amps, depending on the battery.

However, there are several major drawbacks to this system.

- Unless Q1 is capable of handling ridiculously high currents, it will most likely fail *spectacularly*.
- T1 (T is the symbol for a transformer, not L. L is an inductor.) will be unable to handle the 9kW going through it.
- Your wiring will need to be VERY thick. I punched those numbers into a wiring gauge calculator, it said >2000kcmil, which is over 2 inches thick.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Usually lead acid battery cranking current is rated for only 30 seconds. So, your 8 minutes, or even the 2 and a half minutes seems over-optimistic.